# SI4T Error: Error creating bean with name 'JPASearchBinaryContentDAO'

Tags: si4t

I am getting an error when trying to Publish Pages after installing SI4T.

Indexable file extensions are not configured.

'Error creating bean with name 'JPASearchBinaryContentDAO' defined in URL [jar:file:/D:/SDLWeb_Services/Deployer/staging/lib/si4t.jar!/com/tridion/storage/si4t/dao/JPASearchBinaryContentDAO.class]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.tridion.storage.si4t.dao.JPASearchBinaryContentDAO]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is com.tridion.configuration.ConfigurationException: Indexable file extensions are not configured.'

I am using the latest SOLR  version 6.2 and followed the instructions in the docs, including setting up my two cores.  Although the instructions refer to schema.xml which version 6.2 does not have so I created this in the GUI, which I think is correct??

I am running Web 8 CU1 and DXA 1.5.

Please could someone advise as to anything else I can try.  Also, is this error likely to be due to the Core fields?

I have seen a similar issue was raised by Hem Kant but I don't think the solution is the same.

Thank you in advance...

Comment: Richard, it's been a while since I set up SI4T, but looking at the error it looks to be related to indexing of binaries and their file extensions. Perhaps there is some config on the MM schema or the SI4T TBB parameters?

Comment: Did you use the `deployer-install.ps1` provided as part of the DXA Search Module to deploy and configure the SI4T indexer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take a look in the source of the JPASearchBinaryContentDAO class, you'll see that error is thrown when there are no indexable file extensions configured. This happens if either the entire [configuration is null](https://github.com/SI4T/SI4T/blob/301f155f70c07cbe3056257384d0d56dd2fc0dd7/storage-extensions/src/main/java/com/tridion/storage/si4t/dao/JPASearchBinaryContentDAO.java#L75), or if there is [no "Indexer" node with a "DocExtensions" attribute](https://github.com/SI4T/SI4T/blob/301f155f70c07cbe3056257384d0d56dd2fc0dd7/storage-extensions/src/main/java/com/tridion/storage/si4t/dao/JPASearchBinaryContentDAO.java#L78). This is configured in your cd_storage_conf.xml, [an example of which can be seen here](https://github.com/SI4T/SI4T/blob/301f155f70c07cbe3056257384d0d56dd2fc0dd7/storage-extensions/conf/cd_storage_conf_example.xml#L41).